# Как при переходе на другую страницу сохранить цвет ссылки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я так понимаю из за обновления страницы обработчик сбрасывается и цвет ссылки пропадает на странице которую перешел. Как решить?

```
<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
```

```
a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```
const link = document.querySelector('a');

link.addEventListener('click', function(){
    link.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: еще вариант использовать псевдо-класс `visited` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited. Все зависит от вашей задачи.